# Tampermonkey - Issue using jquery and jquery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, tampermonkey

I want to add an "info div" on a website. For this, I add some html via a **Tampermonkey** script:

```
// ==UserScript== 
// @name         New script 
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/ 
// @version      1.1 
// @description  try to take over the world! 
// @author       You 
// @match        http://www.monsite.com/* 
// @grant        GM_getValue 
// @grant        GM_setValue 
// @grant        GM_listValues 
// @grant        GM_addStyle 
// @grant        GM_getResourceText 
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js
// ==/UserScript== 
/* jshint -W097 */ 
'use strict'; 

var html = "<div id='myDiv'>CONTENT</div>"; 
$('body').append(html);

$(function() {
    $( "#myDiv" ).draggable();
});
```

When I try to move it, I got a console error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.style is not a function
```

For information, I got the same issue if I want to use *$.slideToggle()*..

Any idea how to fix this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try this:

```
$(function() {
    var $html = $("<div id='myDiv'>CONTENT</div>"); 
    $html.draggable();
    $('body').append($html);
});
```

Also check the Scripts that are running on the site. They may interfere with your code or vice-versa if they are running JQuery already.

Comment: With this one, I got the same error at

`$html.draggable();`

Comment: I see the site use jquery 1.7.. can this be the source of the issue ?